# Mobile devices not being able to use media queries

Tags: css

So i'm trying to use media queries and it just doesn't work on devices with 800+px in height.

```
 @media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .logo {
   display: inline-block;
    position: sticky;
    color: white;
    font-size: 4vw;
    margin-top: 2.7vw;
 }


 .lista{
   text-decoration: none;
   position: sticky;
   color: white;
   padding-bottom: 7px;
   transition: .1s all linear;
   font-size: 3vw;
   display: inline-block;
   font-weight: bold;
 }

  header ul.navigace{
   float: right;
   margin-top: 3vw;
   word-spacing: 1vw;
 }


  header{
   background: rgb(31, 9, 110);
   position: sticky;
   height: 9vw;
 }
```

tried even setting maximum height and stuff and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox for this?

Comment: umm what is that?

Comment: What exactly is your request? Does it work up to 800 pixels or after 800 pixels? If it's one of them, why does your code have 600px?

Comment: If you want to change something relative to 800px in height add media query with height, you have width.

Comment: it works only up to 800 pixels in height but i don't want to to be capped. The width is for mobile devices

Comment: @Ankit One is to make a [mcve] here, within the question, and not a link to any other site

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it for mobile devices, this width should be up to 767px (as you did). However, if you want to customize it for tablet and desktop devices, you can give a certain range. It is possible to achieve this with the following code.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {..}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use media query at 800 + px in height then you have to do like`@media (min-height:800px){}`
your code in your code you are not closing the bracket  "}"  at the end that's why it's not working